# seq stops as soon as it reaches a constructor

Tags: haskell

[RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html#x_dD1) explains that seq stops as soon as it reaches a constructor.

```
case1 = 1:repeat undefined `seq` "OK"
case2 = (undefined,undefined) `seq` "OK"
```

We have

```
1:repeat undefined = (:) 1 (repeat undefined)
(undefined,undefined) = (,) undefined undefined
```

I understood why case1 function return "OK".
But why the case2 function return "OK" too ?
I thought that case2 will return "Preluded.undefined" because in the first case 1 is evaluated so I thought that undefined should be evaluated in the second case too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RWH says,

> Consider the value `(1+2):(3+4):[]`. If we apply `seq` to this, it will evaluate the `(1+2)` thunk.

This is incorrect, as a comment from Phil Thomas in the online version points out:

> In ghci, if you enter the following:
>
> ```
> let x = (1+2):(3+4):[]
> seq x True
> :print x
> ```
>
> You will see:
>
> ```
> x = [(_t1::Integer),(_t2::Integer)]
> ```
>
> The `(1+2)` has not been evaluated. The cons is an infix operator that appears to come after the `(1+2)`, but it really is the first thing encountered by the seq.

We can think of `seq` as being defined as:

```
⊥ `seq` b = ⊥
a `seq` b = b
```

In order to determine whether a value is bottom, it must be evaluated only up to its *outermost* constructor. The outermost constructor of `1 : repeat undefined` is not `1`, it is `(:)`. For example, you can visualize `1 : []` as:

```
 (:)
 / \
1   []
```

The outermost constructor in this representation is the **topmost** constructor.

This means that `1 : repeat undefined` will be evaluated to `_ : _`, not `1 : _` (where `_` represents an unevaluated thunk).

Similarly, the outermost constructor of `(undefined, undefined)` is `(,)` and it will be evaluated to `(_, _)`, not `(undefined, _)` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

> But why the case2 function return "OK" too ?

Because both `undefined`s are inside the `(,)` constructor and thus not evaluated.

> I thought that case2 will return "Preluded.undefined" because in the first case 1 is evaluated

`1` isn't evaluated in the first case - the evaluation stops with `(:)` (the first constructor), as the book says. `` undefined : undefined `seq` "OK" `` still evaluates to "OK".

Comment: RHW indicates "Consider the value (1+2):(3+4):[]. If we apply seq to this, it will evaluate the (1+2) thunk¨. So I thought that 1 should be evaluated.

Comment: `1+2` is not the same as `(,) 1 2` or `(,) undefined undefined` in your question.  One is a computation the other is a data construction.

Comment: @neo2500 That seems to be a mistake in the book. ``undefined:(3+4):[] `seq` "OK"`` evaluates to "OK" - the left operand of `:` is definitely not evaluated.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson But `(1+2) : ...` is the same as `(1+2, ...)` (in terms of where the expression is relative to the constructor). The line in the book seems to be just wrong (or both neo and me are misreading it).

Comment: @neo2500 The book isn't really clear about what "apply `seq` to this" means. `seq (1+2) "OK"` does evalute `1+2` to `3`, but you can check in GHCi that `(1+2):(3+4):[] `seq` "OK"` does not evalute any element of the list: `> let x = (1+2):(3+4):[]; > seq x "OK"; > :sprint x  --> x = _`